# Method to count the nodes in a tree

Tags: java

I understand how to count the nodes in a binary search tree if your method parameter is the root node, I'm just wondering if there's a way to count them if the method call parameter is a node other than the root?

I originally had:

```
public int size(BSTNode cur)
{
    if (cur == null)
        return 0;
    return 1 + size(cur.getLeft()) + size(cur.getRight());  
}
```

This will only work if the node I use in the method call is the root, otherwise it only returns the number of nodes in a subtree, not the entire tree.

Answer (score 3):

If your tree nodes have a link to a parent, you could go up all the way to the root (i.e. the node that has no parent):

```
TreeNode node = ...
while (node.parent != null) {
    node = node.parent; // Go up the tree
}
// Now you are at the root, so you can count all nodes
```

Otherwise, the task is impossible, because there is no way to reach other nodes higher up in the tree.